# Inno Setup - Prevent installation and execute program when installer is executed without administrator privileges

Tags: inno-setup

I want my installer to check admin rights **at the beginning**, and if not to execute a program that popups a form and exit the installation

```pascal
procedure MyAfterInstall(); 
var 
  MyProgChecked: boolean;
  ErrorCode : Integer;      
begin    
  MyProgChecked := not IsAdminLoggedOn;    
  if MyProgChecked =true then   
    ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('\users\public\EzPasteFiles\RAADMIN.EXE'), '',      
              '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait,ErrorCode ) ; 
  ExitProcess(0);  
end;
```

My question is, where to put and how to make **RAADMIN.EXE** available to the procedure?

I have tried without success

```
Source: "c:\Dropbox\word\EzPasteOffice64Win10\RunAsAnAdminTutorial\RAADMIN.exe"; \
  DestDir: "\users\public\EzPasteFiles"; AfterInstall: MyAfterInstall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for administrator privileges and conditionally abort the installation, use  [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup).

To extract some file before installation, use [`ExtractTemporaryFile` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfile)

Of course, this all makes sense, only if you set [`PrivilegesRequired=lowest`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired). Otherwise your installer will never run without administrator privileges in the first place.

```pascal
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=lowest

[Files]
Source: "C:\source\path\RAADMIN.exe"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var 
  ErrorCode: Integer;
  Path: string;
begin    
  Result := True;

  if not IsAdminLoggedOn then
  begin
    Log('No admin privileges, executing RAADMIN');
    ExtractTemporaryFile('RAADMIN.exe');
    Path := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\RAADMIN.exe');
    if not Exec(Path, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode) then
    begin
      MsgBox('Error executing RAADMIN', mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
    Result := False; { abort installation }
  end;
end;
```

---

*Though if it's just about displaying a form, did you consider implementing the form in Inno Setup?*

Comment: Thanks it works well but I noticed a strange behavior. The form popups but reappears a 2nd time after I correctly unload it...Any idea why? I have tried with other forms

Comment: We do not know anything about your application. Did you try to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

Place your code in **function InitializeSetup()** which is called as very first when  installer starts.

If you return **False** from this function the installer will quit immediately.

Details: https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm